# C++ temporary variables in initialization list

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

In C++, is there any way to have something like a temporary variable in an initialization list. I want to initialize two constant members with the same instance of something without having to pass that something in, remove the const requirement, use a Factory (i.e. pass it in but have the factory generate it to hide it from the API user), or have temp actually be a member variable.

I.e. something like

```
Class Baz{
    const Foo f;
    const Bar b;
    Baz(Paramaters p):temp(p),f(p,temp),b(p,temp){ //temp is an instance of Something
                                                  // But NOT A member of Baz
    // Whatever
    }
}
```

instead of

```
Class Baz{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    Baz(Paramaters p){
        Something temp(p);
        f = Foo(p,temp)
        b = Bar(p,temp)
    }
}
```

or

```
Class Baz{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    Baz(Paramaters p,Something s):f(p,s),b(p,s){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In C++11 you could use delegating constructors:

```
class Baz{
    const Foo f;
    const Bar b;
    Baz(Paramaters p) : Baz(p, temp(p)) { } // Delegates to a private constructor
                                            // that also accepts a Something
private:
    Baz(Paramaters p, Something const& temp): f(p,temp), b(p,temp) {
        // Whatever
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, I don't think I want to make this depend on C++11 just do avoid this problem. Its a library and I'd imagine some people might object to integrating it if they had to start using C++11

Comment: @imichaelmiers: I see. Do you have control over the definition of `Something`, `Foo`, and `Baz`? For instance, could you add a member function to `Foo` that returns the `Something` object it was constructed with? (so that you could use it in the initialization of `b` as `b(p,f.get_something())`

Comment: What would you do in the case when the public constructor has signature Baz(Foo a, Foo b) and the private constructor has the same signature Baz(Foo a, Foo temp)?  Then, which constructor to use is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of patterns to achieve this.

In C++11 use delegating constructors:

```
class Baz {
public:
    Baz(Paramaters p) :
        Baz{p, Something{p}}
    {}
private:
    Baz(Paramaters p, Something temp) :
        f{p, temp},
        b{p,temp}
    {}

    const Foo f;
    const Bar b;
};
```

Use a base class:

```
class BazBase {
public:
    BazBase(Paramaters p, Something temp) :
        f{p, temp},
        b{p,temp}
    {}
protected:
    const Foo f;
    const Bar b;
};

class Baz : private BazBase {
public:
    Baz(Paramaters p) :
        BazBase{p, Something{p}}
    {}
};
```

Use a factory method:

```
class Baz {
public:
    static Baz make(Parameters p)
    {
        return {p, Something{p}};
    }
private:
    Baz(Paramaters p, Something temp) :
        f{p, temp},
        b{p,temp}
    {}

    const Foo f;
    const Bar b;
};
```